# Meaning of Lagrangian and Eulerian descriptions of the fluid velocity field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, flow

This arose out of a homework question. I solved it and asked my professor about it, but I think that I disagree with the explanation that was provided to me.

> **Original Problem Statement**
>
> Consider a one-dimensional flow along the x-direction that is created by firing fluid particles at $x=0$ and $0\leq t \leq T$. The velocity of the particle at the time of firing, $t$, is given by $U\frac{t}{T}$, where $U$ and $T$ are constants. The velocity of each particle remains constant after firing.
>
> **a)** Consider a particle fired at time $t_0$. Determine the position $X(t)$ and velocity $U(t)$ at time $t\geq t_0$.
>
> **b)** Develop a field function that describes the velocity of the fluid particles $u(x,t)$.

This is how I reached the solution, but it is unsatisfying, because I do not understand how we can define an Eulerian velocity field when the fluid particles coincide with each other. By definition,
$$U(t) = \frac{U}{T}t_0$$
for a particle fired at time $t_0$. Integrating, we have
$$
X(t) = \frac{U}{T}t_0(t-t_0).
$$
Now, for the Eulerian velocity $u(x,t)$, we must have
$$
u(x,t) = U(t;t_0),
$$
where $U(t;t_0)$ is the velocity of a particle fired at time $t_0$ such that $X(t;t_0)=x$. We can use this constraint to solve for the appropriate $t_0$ and thus get the velocity at $(x,t)$. Skipping some of the math, I found
$$
t_0 = \frac{1}{2}t\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t^2-4\frac{T}{U}x}
$$

Clearly, we must respect $t^2\geq4\frac{T}{U}x$, $x\geq 0$, and $0\leq t \leq T$. If we ignore the negative root, the Eulerian velocity field is
$$
u(x,t) = \frac{U}{T}\frac{1}{2}\left(t+\sqrt{t^2-4\frac{T}{U}x}\right).
$$

My basic physical intuition is this: Particles fired at smaller $t_0$ will be slow and will be overtaken by particles fired at larger $t_0$. Therefore, the domain will be comprised of many cases of "overlapping" particles. In that case, how can you define a consistent field velocity $u(x,t)$?

My professor says that the negative root can be discarded, because it would yield $t_0=0$ at $x=0$, which is not a valid solution. But I think I disagree with this. For any $(0,t)$ coordinate in $(x,t)$ space, there are two particles that pass through the point. The stationary particle fired at time $t_0=0$ and the particle fired at $t_0=t$. I also plotted some particle trajectories in $(x,t)$ space. We can clearly see that many particles pass over each other.

[image: Particle trajectories]

Am I misunderstanding something in this problem? How do we define $u(x,t)$ if there are multiple particles coincident at $(x,t)$?

Comment: Two "material" particles can't pass through each other. Since the flow is 1D they can't go around each other either. The problem statement doesn't appear to represent any physically possible flow situation. Perhaps the condition "The velocity of each particle remains constant after firing" must be dropped.